# Como descobrir o tamanho de um array de caracteres?

Tags: c++, array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int n =0;

    cout << "Quantos alunos?";
    cin >> n;

    char gabarito[5];
    char respostas[n][5];
    string nome[n];

    for(int g = 0;g < 5;g++){

        cout << "Gabarito: ";
        cin >> gabarito[g];

    }
    for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
        cout << "Nome: ";
        cin >> nome[i];

    for(int j=0;j < 5;j++){

        cout << "Questão ("<<(j+1)<<"): ";
        cin >> respostas[i][5];

    }

}


    cout << "General report"<<"\n";

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << nome[i] <<": ";

        for(int j=0;j<sizeof(respostas);j++){
            cout << respostas[i][j];
        }
    }





}
```

Basicamente como eu faço respostas[i].length em c++?Para mostrar os caracteres que estavam no vetor?

Comment: "*Esse trecho está em Java*" e aquela função `cout`, `cin`? Nunca vi isso em java o,O

Comment: Estava em java* esqueci de editar hehe.

Comment: Na solução que você me deu usando o sizeof(respostas) o console não mostra as letras que eu digitei.

Comment: Hm, é por causa do ´cout´...

Comment: Você diz o cout que tem a matriz respostas[i][j]?O que seria?

Comment: Essa função `cout` acho que ela não ta fazendo o que devia ser feito, não sei pq, deve ser pq eu não conheço muito o C++

Comment: Tente colocar `std::cout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o número de respostas por aluno é fixo (no caso 5), você pode utilizar a função `sizeof` apenas com o primeiro elemento do vetor:

`sizeof(respostas[0])`

---

Respondendo ao comentário: "o programa não mostra as letras digitadas", há um problema na leitura das respostas dos alunos, pois a entrada está armazenando essas respostas em uma posição além do limite do vetor (posição 5) em: `cin >> respostas[i][5];`.

Para solucionar, basta colocar o índice `j`:

```
...
for(int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
     cout << "Questão (" << (j+1) << "): ";
     cin >> respostas[i][j]; // nesta linha
};
...
```

O programa completo fica assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int n = 0;

    cout << "Quantos alunos?";
    cin >> n;

    char gabarito[5];
    char respostas[n][5];
    string nome[n];

    for(int g = 0; g < 5; g++) {
        cout << "Gabarito: ";
        cin >> gabarito[g];
    };

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << std::endl;
        cout << "Nome: ";
        cin >> nome[i];

        for(int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << "Questão (" << (j+1) << "): ";
            // Aqui é j
            cin >> respostas[i][j];
        };
    };

    cout << std::endl;

    cout << "General report"<< std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << nome[i] << ": ";

        // sizeof(respostas[0]) ou sizeof(respostas[i])
        for(int j=0; j < sizeof(respostas[0]); j++)
            cout << respostas[i][j] << " ";
        cout << std::endl;
    };
}
```

Após a execução, a saída do programa:

```
Quantos alunos?3
Gabarito: a
Gabarito: b
Gabarito: c
Gabarito: d
Gabarito: e

Nome: Aluno1
QuestÃ£o (1): a
QuestÃ£o (2): a
QuestÃ£o (3): a
QuestÃ£o (4): a
QuestÃ£o (5): a

Nome: Aluno2
QuestÃ£o (1): b
QuestÃ£o (2): c
QuestÃ£o (3): d
QuestÃ£o (4): a
QuestÃ£o (5): e

Nome: Aluno3
QuestÃ£o (1): e
QuestÃ£o (2): d
QuestÃ£o (3): c
QuestÃ£o (4): b
QuestÃ£o (5): a

General report
Aluno1: a a a a a
Aluno2: b c d a e
Aluno3: e d c b a
```

Outra possibilidade, talvez mais simples, é utilizar a classe [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) da linguagem C++ para armazenar os dados.

Essa classe, entre outras vantagens, disponibiliza o método `size()`, que retorna o número de elementos do vetor (de forma semelhante ao `length` da linguagem Java.

Comment: Muito obrigado, só uma duvida talvez boba sou novo em c++, o que significa o ponto e vírgula depois dos colchetes?

Comment: @Jarwin É um (mal) costume meu, pois costumo programar em C. Na linguagem C++, ele não é necessário :)

Comment: @Jarwin: Apenas para complementar: depois do final de um bloco, após a chave `};`, não é necessário colocar o `;`.  Mas após os colchetes `];` , o ponto e vírgula é necessário para indicar o final de linha

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `sizeof`:

```
#include <iostream>
...

for (j = 0; j < sizeof(respostas); j++) {
   cout << respostas[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Eu quero que o gabarito  saia junto com os nomes. Eu coloquei o código inteiro para melhorar a compreensão.